# How to attach an identifier to spinner item?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a spinner, which contains language options and its items are named from string resources depending on system language. I need something like an identifier for these languages attached to each item. For example, I need to know that the user selected "English" as an option (or "en" if we are talking about identifiers) even though when he selected it, he chose "Englisch" (if the user is german). So how can I attach these kinds of identifiers to my array-list items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest making a simple class to hold the required data.

```
public class Language {

private String identifier;
private String name; //localised name 

...

//we want to show the localised data in the spinner
@Override
public String toString() { 
    return name;
}
```

Then just make a simple ArrayAdapter and overwrite the onItemSelected function of the spinner or just get the selected item whenever you wish to. Something like:

```
List listWithLanguages = getLanguages();
ArrayAdapter<Language> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, listWithLanguages);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter)
...
String identifier = (Language) spinner.getSelectedItem().getIdentifier();
```

Comment: Thank you! That's my way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your string-array items as an identifier.
And can use get the selected item from setting up the listener

> AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {
    You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom adapter that encapsulates the information you care about, then instead of building an adapter that creates a list of localized strings, you create an adapter that creates a list of objects that have the identifier and the localized string together.

Kotlin pseudo code:

```
val strings = loadLocalizedStringsFromArrayItems()
val identifiers = loadIndentifierStringsFromArrayItems()
val listOfPairs = identifiers.zip(string)
val adapter = ArrayAdapter<List<Pair<String, String>>>(listOfPairs)
val spinner.setAdapter(adapter)

// When clicking on the spinner item:
val pair = adapter.getItemAtPosition(clickedPosition)
val identifier = pair.first
val localizedString = pair.second
```